# Linux server remounted to read-only

Tags: linux, permissions

I have tried to find anwser on SF, but no luck.
Nothing worked. (and I have just basic knowledge of linux systems - I'm more developer)

Hour ago I noticed that database is not reacting anymore.
From some reason system went to readonly mode.

Complete server is now, ofc, unavailable.

Server is VPS in Dutch company, and have no idea what I can do with it now to unlock it.

Every suggestion would be more then appriciated.
I tried to save as much of database as possible but there are 20G of images, that would be hard to backup, but I can do that also, if that is something that is smart to do.

Answer (score 1):

Several linux filesystems will go read-only in the event of underlying hardware issues, severe IO latency, or filesystem corruption.

I'd recommend booting a recovery distro (if possible) and run `fsck` checks on your filesystems to ensure they're in a healthy state.

Comment: Tnx a lot for help. After almost 2 hours it just get back to normal. Seems like it was some kind of DC problem, and they like forgot to send email that they would put whole VPS server down so if anyone is actualy working something can know that it is not server fault but tmp break becuase of what ever they were doing... Again, tnx for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things it could be..

I'd check dmesg and syslog (typically found in /var/log) for entries/hints as to why the system went to read-only.

I'd also check the disk space to make sure the drives aren't maxed out. You can use the following command to get a status:

```
df -Th
```

Lastly, I'd check to make sure the system did not run out of inodes and forced the system into a read-only mode. The following command should get you data about used & free inodes:

```
df -i
```

Comment: Tnx a lot for help. After almost 2 hours it just get back to normal. Seems like it was some kind of DC problem, and they like forgot to send email that they would put whole VPS server down so if anyone is actualy working something can know that it is not server fault but tmp break becuase of what ever they were doing... Again, tnx for your answer.